# Creation of aggregate root that contains references to other aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

I would like to model the following entities:
"Person", "Company" and the aggregate that ties the two together "Membership". I have identified that Person and Company are aggregate roots. Thus, "Membership" would hold a reference (id) of both those aggregate roots, plus other value objects/entities that a membership holds (for example the title that the person has for that company).

In my architecture I have the following layers: Api controllers, services, domains, repository. When creating a Membership object, the controller receives two identifiers (for person and for company). Currently the service is responsible for making a call to the CompanyService - to ensure that a company with that id exists and to the PersonService - to ensure a person with that id exists. However, in the Domain model I currently have a constructor that takes in two ids, which makes it feel really anemic. Also, in a further iteration, there will be the addition of a list of references to a third aggregate root, Vehicle. Thus a vehicle can exist by itself, or it can also belong to a membership.

Is this a bad way of modelling these entities? Is there a better way? I have read about the notion of domain services and application services, but my application does not currently have that distinction and I don't know if that concept would help in this case.

Even the behaviour of the aggregate roots feels a bit dry when it comes to functionality related to the other aggregate roots it holds references for: ie. the Membership domain model would have the ability to "Link a car", setting a car for itself, but again, receiving just an identifier that it would add to a list of identifiers.

Comment: The notion that aggregates must only reference other aggregates by ID comes from, or was popularized by, Vaughn Vernon (i think); now, that probably works well for him, but IMO it is a mistake to present this as mandatory, as people face different kinds of problems, and work with different kinds of systems. Evans' original notion of an aggregate is more that it's a bunch of collaborating objects, with the AR acting as an (encapsulating) Facade to them all, while making sure that invariants are maintained within. It's a model element that's a larger organizational unit than class/object. (1/2)

Comment: Vaughn Vernon emphasizes that aggregates define a transactional boundary, but in some cases that view is too DB-centric. It's supposed to be a conceptual consistency boundary, and you may chose to translate that into actual code in different ways. And you can have nested aggregates, and references going out of an aggregate (or you may chose not to make a distinction between the two); you define these boundaries very deliberately, to your advantage (rather then following some generic rule or best practice), and organize domain behavior around these boundaries. (2/2)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović You haven't thought through your position thoroughly enough. The only conceivable purpose for one aggregate (`A`) to directly reference another aggregate (`B`) would be to allow for the former to invoke a method on the latter as part of it's own process (an aggregate's state is private after all). That is, the method body of `A->doSomething` would invoke `B->doAnotherThing`. This is not useful and can be refactored to `A->doSomething(B)`.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Systems are deterministic. Given the inputs we will *know* which entities are required to carryout a use-case. `A` and `B` can be loaded independently and *coordinated* to achieve the above. The result is a cleaner (simpler) system.

Comment: Are you sure `Membership` is the right name here? DDD asks you to model a system according to *behavior*. Notably, the above contains a lot of "this *has* that"-type phrases in lieu of "this *does* that"-type phrases. Of course this will lead to an anemic model. I'll leave you with some food for thought: When I (`Person`) joined my golf course (`Company`) I became a `Member` that can `reserveGolfCart`.

Comment: @king-side-slide: "This is not useful and can be refactored to `A->doSomething(B)`" - you are talking about details (what provides B, and when), I'm talking about dependency structure (doSomething has a dependency on B), and about the mandate that it has to be an ID. Also, you don't just declare things universally "not useful". --- "`A` and `B` can be loaded independently and *coordinated* to achieve the above" - I've said nothing about how to load them; you decide how to inter-reference and load aggregates, and how they will interact, based on domain needs and technical considerations.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Ultimately this discussion is about coupling (so yes, dependency structure). Coupling takes many forms. I am suggesting that *modeling*  `A` such that it can be loaded and coordinated independently of `B` yields lower (looser) coupling. This should be preferred to requiring `B` to be passed to `A` on construction (how else would we achieve nested aggregates?).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović This should be clear because `A` cannot depend on any state encapsulated by `B`, so what would be the point?. Given the above we can plainly see that the interaction of aggregates must be *transient* in nature and at the level of coordination (i.e. part of some process: `A->doSomething(B)`). I believe Evans says as much (though I would have to dig to find it)

Comment: @king-side-slide: "nested aggregates" - looking at it as an encapsulated graph of objects (could be just a few), you could decide to have such a bundle within a boundary of a larger aggregate, just so that you can simplify the coupling and the code within the (outer) aggregate itself. A doesn't depend on internals of B, but on the interface provided by the root entity of B. You could pass B in, or create it internally, or demand it in an abstracted way via a factory on the outer AR. I concede that this may be considered a concept distinct from the DDD aggregate, but it's in the same spirit.

Comment: (Sometimes this can help organize things and write more concise code, but, of course, one should not go overboard with this and create a complex monster of an aggregate. They should generally be small and simple.)

Comment: But, that's a specific thing; in the usual case (distinct boundaries), I don't think that Evans forbids in-memory references to other ARs if convenient. You can still load independently. Interactions are local/transient. Coordination happens at specific points in aggregate lifecycle (beyond its local in-memory existence, if there's access by other users), as defined by the consistency rules established for the model. Now, you can do domain model references via IDs, I'm not saying that you never should, just that it's not the only option - it's a choice, and there are pros and cons.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović An "encapsulated graphs of objects" *is* an aggregate. I'm certainly not suggesting one shouldn't create aggregates. I am arguing that an aggregate shouldn't *hold* (e.g. as a property) a reference to *another* aggregate. Doing so either violates consistency boundaries or is unnecessary. On construction, if `A` *depends* on `B`, then `B` is just an implementation detail of `A` (i.e. We really have one aggregate, `A`, that encapsulates `B`). If not, then `B` should be injected into the *process* in which it is necessary (e.g. `A->doSomething(B)`).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I'm an not arguing against in-memory references between aggregates, rather the semantics of how/when these references should occur. I am suggesting an aggregate *should not* hold a reference to another aggregate as part of it's state, and instead use an identifier. On the other hand an aggregate *may* hold a reference to another aggregate as part of some *transient* process. The only con with the above approach is that it forces you to load `A` and `B` independently (which is truly a pro).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @king-side-slide from what I have read around, it is perfectly fine for an aggregate to keep references to other aggregates in itself, as long as those aggregates are not aggregate roots. This way, all functionality to modify those 'child' aggregates is contained in the aggregate root. For example if A has a reference to B, in order to call B->doSomething() you need to go through A. That is the difference between aggregate and aggregate root. An aggregate can only exists as part of its root, even if it has its own id.

Comment: @Mike I am making no distinction between the terms "aggregate" and "aggregate root" above. From the perspective of our domain, if `A` is an aggregate that contains `B`, then we only have one aggregate, `A`, and `B` is an implementation detail not found in our UL. Clearly a nested graph of objects may, itself, contain a nested graph of objects. The inner-workings of an aggregate may be implemented in any way the business sees fit *provided* it does not contain references to objects outside it's own consistency boundary. It's trivial to synthesize examples illustrating why this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the Domain model I currently have a constructor that takes in two ids, which makes it feel really anemic.

As you described, a membership ties together a person and a company. The important pieces here are the *concept* of a person and a company, not the specific object used to represent them. In that regard, `PersonId` and `CompanyId` are just as good (and more lightweight) than `Person` and `Company`. Is there any significant benefit in having the complete entity objects rather than just their IDs? And how does that trade off with the performance impact of having to load that additional data?

Using IDs to represent entities does not make a model anemic. What is important is to make sure that business rules and constraints do not leak out of domain objects.

> I have read about the notion of domain services and application services, but my application does not currently have that distinction

Your controllers are effectively application services since they orchestrate the execution of business logic (look up aggregates by ID and invoke methods on them).

> the Membership domain model would have the ability to "Link a car", setting a car for itself, but again, receiving just an identifier that it would add to a list of identifiers.

Once again, this is perfectly fine since the *concept* of "linking a car" is modeled in the `Membership` object. What would make this anemic, for example, is adding to the list directly in your controller, because that masks the fact that it is a domain concept.